# Animate backgroundColor of Dialog

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog

I created a Color Tween animation to change the background color of Dialog, but it still doesn't change.

My code:

```
void _showDialog() {
AnimationController? animationController = AnimationController(
    vsync: this,
    duration: const Duration(
      milliseconds: 1000,
    )
);
Animation<Color?>? animation = ColorTween(
  begin: Colors.black54,
  end: Colors.redAccent,
).animate(animationController!.view);


showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Dialog(
        backgroundColor: animation!.value,
        elevation: 6,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
        ),
        child: MyTextWidget(
          onSubmitted: (text) {
            animationController.forward();
          }
      );
    }
).then((value) => {
  print(value)
});
}
```

Then I use *animationController.forward()*, but nothing happens.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: I can't say for sure, but you should try moving the entire dialog with the animation logic in a separate widget class (so showDialog function return the new widget). The reason is that when you call show dialog, it comes out in a different context and also its route is based on the root navigator (ie MaterialApp) so its parent is not the same as where it was called, and that's maybe the values are not updating properly... again, I'm not 100% sure but navigations and dialog are always a pain for the reasons I mentioned.

Comment: Where are you calling animationController.forward() ?

Comment: @bluenile
child: MyTextWidget(
    onSubmitted: (text) {
                animationController.forward();
              }
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no animation because you did not wrap your dialog with any widget that would animate. Please see the working code below the only thing I did was to wrap Dialog with a AnimatedBuider and call animationController.repeat(). You may call animationController.forward from your custom text widget :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      //theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidgets(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidgets extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetsState createState() => _MyWidgetsState();
}

class _MyWidgetsState extends State<MyWidgets> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  void _showDialog() {
    AnimationController animationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: const Duration(
          milliseconds: 1000,
        ));
    Animation<Color> animation = ColorTween(
      begin: Colors.black54,
      end: Colors.redAccent,
    ).animate(animationController.view);

    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          animationController.repeat();
          return AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: animation,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Dialog(
                    backgroundColor: animation.value,
                    elevation: 6,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                    child: Container());
              });
        }).then((value) => {print(value)});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        _showDialog();
        //animationController
      },
      child: const Text("Show Dialog"),
    );
  }
}
```